# Problem with KableExtra output tables in Rmarkdown(RStudio): paste0 function

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

This is my Rsweave reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\alpha$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\tau$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\sigma$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\beta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\gamma$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\mu$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{$\Delta$}

\begin{document}

This is a table

    <<summarymatrix,echo=FALSE>>=
    library(knitr)
    library(kableExtra)
alpha='\u03b1'; tau='\u03c4'; sigma='\u03c3'; beta='\U03B2'; gamma='\u03b3'; mu='\u03BC'; Delta='\u0394'

    dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]
    colnames(dt)=c('Sample1','Sample2','Sample3')
    rownames(dt)=c(paste0(mu),paste0(tau),paste0(sigma),paste0(beta),paste0(Delta))


    dt
    @

    \end{document}
```

There are two problems:

First the Delta rowname is placed at the wrong positionin my output table. Should be in the 5-th row. And the first rowname should be mu.

Second, why I can not have repeated symbols as rows? For example, how can I put the second and the thirs rownames as Beta?

How can I solve this?

Comment: @user2554330 This is my first time with Rmardown and LATEX. I edited and included  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your preamble is messed up. You need the inputenc package to get `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, and you shouldn't be declaring B5 to be 7 different things.

Here is your document with those things fixed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B1}{$\alpha$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3C4}{$\tau$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3C3}{$\sigma$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B2}{$\beta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B3}{$\gamma$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3BC}{$\mu$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{394}{$\Delta$}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

This is a table

<<summarymatrix,echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
alpha='\u03b1'; tau='\u03c4'; sigma='\u03c3'; beta='\U03B2'; gamma='\u03b3'; mu='\u03BC'; Delta='\u0394'

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]
colnames(dt)=c('Sample1','Sample2','Sample3')
rownames(dt)=c(paste0(mu),paste0(tau),paste0(sigma),paste0(beta),paste0(Delta))


dt
@

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: pdf output]

That looks more or less fine to me (except for the alignment on the last line).

The reason you can't repeat rownames is that they are used to identify rows.  If you had two rows named beta, what would `dt["beta", ]` give?  If you want repeated values, just add an extra column.

Comment: Im having this error message @user2554330: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode character mu (U+B5)`

Comment: That probably comes from your multiple declarations of character B5.